# Извлечение даты из БД в datepicker ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Ситуация такая, как извлекать дату из базы в такой вот контрол:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но только чтобы вместо дд.мм.гг, отображались текущие данные из базы например 31.03.2017

Сейчас во вью такой вид контрола

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data_add_upd, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data_add_upd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data_add_upd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Какой тип имеет `Data_add_upd`? Если `DateTime`, то используйте `model.Data_add_upd.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: можно так model.Data_add_upd.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")

Comment: Ошибка. Шаблоны могут использоваться только с выражениями обращения к полю, обращения к свойству, индекса одномерного массива и настраиваемого индексатора с одним параметром.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете элемент типа DateTime - вам может помочь экземплярный метод `ToShortDateString()`. В случае, когда передается коллекция, есть специальный хелпер `Html.DropDownListFor`.